# Change Folder View, possibly Namespace Extension?

Tags: c#, windows-shell

We're developing an application and we came across a screenshot of Sharepoint integrated into Windows Explorer. I was wondering how I could create a folder like this for our application.

In this special folder, it wouldn't actually show real files, it would be connected to our server software and pull a list of records (which relate to files). From this screen we will be able to open files from our server, and save files to our server. The files that are on our server are not stored as a regular file structure, and does not allow for any sort of standard user credentials - all of that is handled by our server software.

I was looking at namespace extensions, but couldn't find a suitable example. I'm looking for examples in C# (.Net 4) preferably.

Any help or thoughts (or possibly alternatives) would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to a screenshot of the sharepoint functionality I'm looking to recreate:

[image: Sharepoint Screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if a shell extension is the best choice for what you need, but there's some info here on how to write one in .NET 4.0:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx.

For what it's worth, before .NET 4.0 this was not previously supported by Windows (for various reasons described here:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx

Comment: hey - Thanks, I took a look at the links, and it looks like those are more shell extensions for files that already exist. I was hoping to have only virtual files (really pointers to a server side file without a network share). I think what I'm looking for is more of a namespace extension, if I'm not mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: @Svelluto Those may have been the examples, but the shell extensions are actually "Shell Namespace Extensions" -- they can be used for logical entities that doesn't exist on disk. It's all up to the implementation of the interfaces...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [shell namespace extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Take a look at [EZNamespaceExtensions.Net](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm) which makes this process a lot easier.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of EZNamespaceExtensions.Net.

Comment: Big problem with EZNamespaceExtension.NET. It hasn't been updated for a long time. LogicNP seems to have lost their interest in EZNamespaceExtension.NET because there hasn't been a release with new a handful of features since 2010. No .NET 4 support and no support for Windows 8 ribbon toolbar

Comment: While there have been no new major versions (no need), we have been making new builds for minor updates from time to time. .Net 4.0: Again untrue - in fact, with .Net 4.0 support for side-by-side runtimes, developing nses in .Net just got easier! Win8 ribbon: MS has not documented the API to do ribbon integration. If you have links to relevent document, please share so we can add this functionality.